# how do I show man all users saved in core data

Tags: swift, core-data

can anyone help me please

how do I show all users

```
import CoreData
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var Username: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
var array = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func Login(_ sender: Any)
{

    let request       = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    //let predicate     = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@ && password == %@", Username.text! ,Password.text! )
           //request.predicate = predicate

    request.fetchLimit = 1

    do
    {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context     = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let users       = try! context.fetch(request)
         // for var i in 0 ..< Users.count

        if(users.count > 0)

        {
            let user                        =  users.first as? Users

            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard   = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController          = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UsersData") as? UsersData
            nextViewController?.userInfo    =   user
            self.present(nextViewController!, animated:true, completion:nil)

        }

        else

         {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "",message:"No user Found", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let OKAction        = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
}


@IBAction func RegisterButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegisterPage") as? RegisterPage
    self.present(nextViewController!, animated:true, completion:nil)
}

}
```

this is where I save values

this is where I get I data from

```
class RegisterPage: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var UsernameRegister: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Mobile: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var PasswordRegister: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func Register(_ sender: Any) {

    if (UsernameRegister.text == "" || email.text == "" || Mobile.text == "" ||  PasswordRegister.text == "" )
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Note",message:"All fields are required", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else if !validateEmail(candidate:email.text!)
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "",message:"Email not valid", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    else if(UsernameRegister.text != "" && email.text != "" && Mobile.text != "" && PasswordRegister.text != "" )
    {

                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                let userData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:"Users",into:context)

                userData.setValue(UsernameRegister.text, forKey: "name")
                userData.setValue(email.text, forKey: "email")
                userData.setValue(Mobile.text, forKey: "mobile")
                userData.setValue(PasswordRegister.text, forKey: "password")
                print(userData)

                    do
                {
                    try context.save()
                    print(userData)

                }
                catch
                {
                    print("error")
                }
            }



    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    let nextViewController = 



storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
    self.present(nextViewController!, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: It looks like you're already fetching every `User`. In what way is your code not working as desired?

Comment: I want to show every user in table view cell but its not showing

Comment: [<Users: 0x600000084920> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://381B26B0-9105-45C8-B425-F2DD827AEB87/Users/p1> ; data: <fault>), <Users: 0x60000008b810> (entity: Users; id:  ; data: <fault>),             This is the result its showing

Comment: You haven't included any table view-related code in your question. What have you tried?

Comment: its done thanks sir..